# Objects in edit mode are all black

Tags: edit-mode

I have created two bezier circles, then converted them to meshes. When I press <kbd>tab</kbd> to enter edit mode, the objects appear completely black.

You can see the exact tutorial I am [following at 6:20 of this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=51aTcZuuWW4&t=6m20s)

Why do they appear black, and not have any subdivisions? Is this a problem with blender, or is there a setting I need to change?

Edit Mode
[image]

Edit Mode + Wireframe view
[image]

Comment: Are you sure you remembered to convert the Bezier curves to meshes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what i can see in the image your object has about 166000 Vertices. In Edit Mode vertices are displayed in a certain size independent from the polygon size, so it may well be that you only see the black vertices, while all edges are hidden because of the vertex "display size". Here is an example with 4 rings of increasing vertex density:

[image]

Also none of your vertices is selected right now, so this would explain why the mesh appears in black. So i guess when you hit <kbd>A</kbd> then your rings will turn from black to light orange (the color of selected vertices)

Maybe you had added a subdivision modifier to your Curve ? When converting your curve to a mesh the subdivision modifier would be applied...

Comment: That's a good a pretty good guess Gaia, I thought that maybe he had a default black texture assigned.  166000 vertices, I suspect you are correct.

Comment: you are correct I had the same issue. I was creating a landscape and then added a subdivision and from then on it was black. When it came to baking my textures it wouldn't work.
When I press `A` it does turn into orange color which is what I'm use to, but I'm not sure if that will solve the issue

Comment: **Tip:** *User Preferences > Themes > 3D Viewport* > **Vertex Size** try to change px or use edge select mode to hide vertices.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for threadmancy but this may help people in future.
There's a possibility that blender has flipped the lighting of those objects. if you select all of the vertices of the objects and then go into Mesh>normals> and try recalculating outside. If that doesn't work go into Mesh>normals> recalculate inside.
This is how i solved a similar issue i had. good luck.

Answer (score -1):

What fixed this issue for me is:
Material>shading> enable the checkbox that

Comment: Incomplete answer.