# Objects are a dark grey in edit mode

Tags: objects, edit-mode

I'm a blender newbie and must have touched some settings that have turned objects a dark grey color in edit mode and I can't edit them.
I'm sorry if this is a silly question, but I've tried to resolve it on my own without success.

I've searched but no joy. Reset blender to defaults, uninstalled and re-installed blender 3.5 to no avail.
This started happening today, as I was following a hair tutorial. Must've inadvertently touched something.
This happens with any object imported or created.
Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks.
[image]

FYI I've tried the suggestion

Comment: Please add an image of your complete Blender window. You can do that via Blender's Window > Save Screenshot menu. Then edit your question and add the image. It would also help if you could share the Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions on that page to add the link to your question.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/16083/2214 ... User Preferences > Themes > 3D Viewport > Vertex Size try to change px or use edge select mode to hide vertices.